# Run C++ Code Online?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

Is there a website I can go to to run C++ code online? I have seen a few compilers, but is there one that can also receive input from `cin`? I want one that can basically host a C++ .exe online, and even more preferable is if it is like the VC++ platform.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to give [rextester](http://rextester.com/XYSX22503) a try. Currently g++ 4.7.2 with boost libraries and ability to supply compiler args.

**Edit**
Visual C++ is also supported now.

Comment: You just can't access the winapi. ;)

Comment: @Adrian can you give an example?

Comment: @ren, it will compile but not link.  Prolly due to security concerns. https://rextester.com/HHWYUW58463

Comment: It is not free. You have to pay to use it with VC++

Answer (score 11):

http://ideone.com/  Can compile several languages, and supports stdin

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) can do that. It's possible to specify *stdin* there.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Microsoft's online compiler seems to no longer be active :(

---

Microsoft research have made an online version of Visual C++ here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

<s>It (currently?) only compiles the code and does not run it so you won't be able to check `cin` though :(</s>

Running code is now supported.

Comment: Hopefully they will develop it further, it could get big.

Comment: It is functional now and use latest compiler available (e.g. under development or CTP) which is good

Comment: site under maintenance!

Comment: Site not available.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the best online tools seem to be

**Special Online Compilers**

https://cppinsights.io shows, how C++ introduces conversions, etc. and interprets the source code (current clang based)

https://godbolt.org compare C++ compilers, show disassembly, run (many current compilers including Microsoft VCC and embedded compilers)

http://quick-bench.com create and compare benchmarks (current g++ and clang)

https://www.onlinegdb.com, includes gdb debugger (g++ 7.4.0)

**Online Compilers that let you set compile flags**

https://wandbox.org (current g++ and clang)

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com (g++ 9.2.0)

https://repl.it/languages/cpp11 (clang 7.0.0)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php = codingground (g++ 7.1.1)

https://tio.run/#cpp-clang (g++ 8.3.1 and clang 7.0.1)

https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc (g++ 7.4.0, clang 6.0.0, VS C++ 2015 Update 1)

**Online Compilers that do not let you set compile flags**

https://www.jdoodle.com (g++ 9.2.0)

https://www.codechef.com/ide (g++ 9.1.0)

https://ideone.com (g++ 8.3.0 and clang 8.0.0)

https://paiza.io (clang 8.0.0)

https://www.codiva.io/c (clang 7.1.0)

https://code.labstack.com/cpp (g++ 8.3.0)

All listed compilers support C++17 code

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ has a built in GDB debugger and lets you set compiler flags (but the box is hidden under the config menu)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following site is what you're aiming for: http://codepad.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is [Wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/), which offers GCC and Clang to its latest versions (as of Nov 2018). It has `stdin`.

I wouldn't say it's a VC++ platform though.

Answer (score 0):

TutorialsPoint's [C++ Coding Ground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) lets you save and compile multiple source files at a time, which can be useful at times, and gives you a GNU bash console to play around with.  It's not as convenient for sharing code as sites like Ideone, however.

[Note: While it only has links to C++, C++0x, and C++11 environments, you can compile code for C++14 by specifying the compiler option `-std=c++1y`.  I'm not sure if it has any experimental C++17 support, however.]

Answer (score 0):

[repl.it](https://repl.it) can compile, run, and execute [C++](https://repl.it/site/languages/cpp) and [C++11](https://repl.it/site/languages/cpp11). It's also interactive and you can ask for user input in realtime.